# A blank gap between last and first slide using .next() with jQuery

Tags: jquery

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfNZ2/) and code below:

```
function slider() { 
    var activeSlide = $(".slideshow img.active");
    var firstSlide = $(".slideshow img:first-of-type");
    var lastSlide = $(".slideshow img:last-of-type");
activeSlide                  
    .removeClass("active")      
    .next()                     
    .addClass("active");      
if (activeSlide.length === 0) {
firstSlide.addClass("active");
}
} 
setInterval(function () {
slider();
}, 3000);
```

Once it gets to the last slide, there is a pause and blank gap before going back to the first slide.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? When I inspect the element, I can see the "active" class looping through as it should, but it disappears for a second on the last one before re-appearing again on the first.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is who is the activeSlide.
You can change in something like this:

```
activeSlide.removeClass("active");
// You have to update the reference for the if statement that follows!!
activeSlide = activeSlide.next();                     
activeSlide.addClass("active");
```

If fact, if you do `console.log($(activeSlide).attr('src'))` you can see the 4 images and then `undefined`, because of this problem.
Like this should work, I was playing with your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

the change - DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/UfNZ2/4/

```
  activeSlide = activeSlide                  
   .removeClass("active")      
   .next();                     
   activeSlide.addClass("active");
```

---

**REASON** for the change

when you use the following code

```
activeSlide                  
   .removeClass("active")      
   .next()                     
   .addClass("active");      

  if (activeSlide.length === 0) {
    firstSlide.addClass("active");
  }
```

when you are on the last slide, your code doesn't find the next slide and doesn't update anything to active and because activeSlide variable is not updated before the if condition which means activeSlide is still pointing to last slide and its length = 1, hence condition doesn't pass and a blank come in between

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for the gap:**

When you are in the last slide:

```
activeSlide.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
```

removes the `active` class from it. At this point you do not have any *active* slides (i.e. nothing is shown).

And in the next line, you are doing:

```
// this will not be 0 at this point as activeSlide is still the last slide
if (activeSlide.length === 0) {
    firstSlide.addClass("active"); // this won't be executed as activeSlide.length is 1
}
```

And then you re-run the function only after 3 seconds, which means 3 seconds when no slide is displayed. This is the delay you are seeing.

**Solution:** Instead you should do:

```
if (activeSlide.next().length === 0) {
    firstSlide.addClass("active");
}
```

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UfNZ2/5/